# cordovaでプッシュ通知時にアイコンにバッジを表示する方法

Tags: android, cordova

cordovaを使用して、androidアプリを開発していますが、
下記プラグインを利用してプッシュ通知を行っています。

プッシュ通知時に、アイコンにバッジを表示する方法がわかりません。
ご存知のかたがいればお教えください。

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin